# crossfading effect with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

I want to create crossfading effect with two AVPlayer, one player for current track and other for nextTrack. where player one is my central player(tracking remote control event and progress), on player one did finish playing event second player become central player. Thanx!

Comment: check here: https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cephalopod